# how do I make my wifi actually use these parent control settings?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, parental-controls

[ubee router parent controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOGvm.png)

[image]

I create a "kid1" user in this admin interface, but where do I login as kid one? When I connect to the wifi from Mac OS or iOS it just wants the normal wifi password. Do I enter this new password instead? It doesn't seem to work. I guess what I really want is a system like they have in coffee shops that boots people off the wifi after X minutes. And then requires them to come get a new password or wait N more minutes before they get access again.

This use case for this is I want to limit my kids Netflix viewing to just 30 mins at a time via shutting off JUST their wifi, not the whole house wifi.

Ubee DDW262.G Wireless Cable Modem and Router

Comment: Parental control on those modems applying parental control rules to anybody except those who "trusted". Trusted in modem's means is a list of computers identified by their MAC addresses. Start reading from page 59 [official documentation](http://www.ubeeinteractive.com/sites/default/files/file_resources/DDW262%20Subscriber_User_Guide%20Chile%20.pdf) that describes how parental control works on these modems  in more details.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer here is what Alex said in his comment. If your kids have multiple devices and you don't have the MAC addresses for them (or if they're exceptionally talented for their age and understand that MAC addresses can be spoofed), this method of yours will simply not work and enter you into a never-ending game of whack-a-mole.

You have two good options here, I think.

1. Skip the technical controls and go straight to parenting controls. Gather up *all* the "hidden" devices if they're circumventing your rules and apply punishments as appropriate.
2. If you really want the technical route, purchase a cheap WiFi access point and connect it to your network. Use that one for the kids, and set the password for the main one to something only you know. Then, a simple outlet timer on the kids access point will do the trick.